# How do I initialise a tuple with a raw array member such as std::tuple<T[N]>?

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer, stdtuple

As far as I can tell from the standard `std::tuple` has no restrictions regarding its member types that would disallow raw arrays. So this should be a valid tuple: `std::tuple<char[3]>`. However, I don't seem to be able to initialise it: [Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/ecz1ozxf8)

```cpp
char const hi[3] = "hi";
std::tuple<char[3]> tup; // fine
std::get<0>(tup)[0] = 'h'; // fine but not initialisation

std::tuple<char[3]> const tup1 = hi; // nope
std::tuple<char[3]> const tup2{hi}; // nope
std::tuple<char[3]> const tup3(hi); // nope
std::tuple<char[3]> const tup4 = std::make_tuple(hi); // nope
std::tuple<char[3]> const tup5 = std::make_tuple<char[3]>(hi); // nope
```

Which produces all sorts of different error messages.

So my questions are:

- Should a `std::tuple<T[N]>` be legal?
- **How do I initialise it correctly?**

---

*Note:* **Yes**, I am fully aware I could put a `std::array` or a `std::string` or any other container in the tuple.

Comment: It's not possible to initialize an array from another array to begin with.

Comment: `std::array` instead of c-array. c-array is not copy-able or moveable since it decays to pointer.

Comment: I don't want to copy a raw array, I want to (at best) copy a tuple. I don't care how tuple implements that.

Comment: *Should a std::tuple<T[N]> be legal?* it is very easy to create useless/corrupted templates in C++. Just substitute something explicitly so no SFINEA occurs. What is the meaning of illegal anyway? What is the purpose of it?

Comment: @ALX23z Legal in the sense that tuple is intended to support having a member of such type.

Comment: @bitmask well, with `char[]` you can still apply get and fill it - so technically it is usable. It is more of `char[]` limitation that the language interprets it very differently depending on the context. I wouldn't advise to use it. They are not going to explicitly forbid you from using it.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the comments covered what is the issue, however, I would like to add that you cannot do this for the same reason why you cannot do the following:

```
    const char hi[3] = "hi";
    const char hi_copy[3] { hi }; // Compile time error.
```

The tuple constructor is just trying to wrap up the above initialization.
What you can do is the following:

```
    const char* hi = new char[3] {'h', 'i', '\0'};
    std::tuple<const char*> const tup2{ hi };
```

Which is obvusly an ugly hack, and should not be used.

You should also keep in mind that c-type arrays are behaving like pointers, consider the following:

```
    const char hi[3] = "hi";        
    std::cout << "Second letter of hi var is " << *(hi + 1);
```

Incrementing `hi` by one will actually move the pointer, and dereferencing the value that pointer points to will produce its value.

In a nutshell: C and C++ are different languages, its just so happens to be that C++ has extremely good support for C. It will work 99.9% of time, you just hit where the compatibility is not perfect.

Comment: C-style arrays are not pointers to my knowledge. They decay to pointers at the slightest provocation, but `T[N]` is a distinct type from `T*`. For illustration, check out the various overloads for raw arrays such as `std::begin`, `std::size`, and so on. Your observation that copying the tuple leads to an (illegal) attempt to copy the array is likely correct. However, the language-lawyer in me considers this an implementation oversight of tuple, **hence** the question. E.g., you wouldn't expect that copying a `std::array<T,N>` breaks just because implementations typically carry a `T[N]`.

Comment: You are correct, I've edited this part of the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use std::array instead of the pointer array.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

Comment: There are no pointers involved here anywhere, and as I stated, I am fully aware of the existence of `std::array`.